# Wrapping simple statement in a function in java?

Tags: java, efficiency, functions

I was working on neo4j graph database in java. To get the reference node of this db:

```
    GraphDatabaseService graphDb=new EmbeddedGraphDatabase(DB_PATH);

    Node Root=graphDb.getReferenceNode()
```

I always forget to prefix graphDb when calling getReferenceNode(). So what I did :

```
   public Node getRootNode(){
   return graphDb.getReferenceNode(); }
```

Now after doing this , I thought this to be overkill as I am replacing a simple statement with a function call which surely has overhead but using getRootNode seems more intuitive to me.

So my question is am I right in thinking that doing the above mentioned thing is inefficient? Or does it not affect performance that much?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also just store the referenceNode in a variable as it is constant per `GraphDatabaseService`.

You can also declare it as a `final` instance variable in the constructor of your service to document that.

Comment: wow.... did not think about that :)

Answer (score 8):

In modern Java, function calls are practically free. If it is called rarely, you won't notice the overhead. If it gets called frequently, the JIT will inline the call, eliminating any overhead.

Comment: You're probably right. But I remember times when calls to simple getters in loops drastically decreased performance. These were the Java 1.4/1.5 days.

Comment: @Falcon, yes, the first JITs weren't so sophisticated, but they improved greatly since the early days. I can't exactly define which JVM version "modern" above refers to, but my guess is Java 5 and above.

Comment: @Falcon, sure it wasn't the Java 1.3 days?

Comment: @Thorbjørn Ravn Andersen: 100% sure. I recall an *extreme* performance gain by removing a simple getter for an image's width/height from a loop header during the Java 1.5 times. I do not know whether I used 1.4 or 1.5, but 1.5. was definitely rolled out then.

Comment: @Falcon: In that particular case there may have been something (such as different overridden implementations of the getter in the class hierarchy) preventing the JIT from inlining the call. I'm pretty sure even the 1.4 JVMs could inline method calls at least some of the time.

Answer (score 3):

Think about it again.

**1. YAGNI - You ain't gonna need it.**
Do you really need to wrap the function? How often and in how many places do you resolve a root node - and most importantly - do you expect to add additional behaviour to this method later on?

**2. Does it really improve readability?**
This is highly subjective. In my eyes, both variants are almost equal in readability. I'd even prefer the first one if I don't really need the wrapper because I don't want to add behaviour later on, as it's easier to debug, one less level to step through.

**3. Performance**
This is a minor concern here. I doubt you call that method very often. When you call it in a loop, it could have a severe impact on performance. The overhead itself is negligible for single function calls.

**4. Design Decision**
Do you want to hide the graphDB Member completely, i.e. behind an interface? Then by all means create a whole abstraction of it with all the methods necessary.

That said, the increased readability is highly subjective (in your eyes only) while adding a new layer that could potentially lead to a performance loss. That's fine if you need that wrapper because you expect to add additional behaviour later on and your code is sprinkled wich calls of `getReferenceNode()`. If you just have a single call or very few calls of getReferenceNode and you don't plan to add additional behaviour later, then I'd not create that wrapper.

Comment: *Performance* - I think the work done by `graphDb.getReferenceNode()` is going to be a lot heavier than what is involved in a single function call, making that argument pretty much moot in a situation like this.

Answer (score 3):

A classic example of premature optimization. When writing code you must feel free to add all the structure you see fit. Later, a profiler will tell you where you need to optimize.

Comment: if I am gonna use profiler later would not it be a problem to change working code later on and face problems?

Comment: Optimization based on Big O Notation (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation) is the only one that matters also before measuring performance. Any other must be backed by profiling, better if in real situations.

Answer (score 1):

Use a profiler to test this. Sometimes, it's better to increase readability if there's not such a great performance penalty.

Comment: never used profiler... can u point to any good profiler for mac

Comment: jvisualvm is available in the Java developer package downloadable from Apple Developer Connection (free registration)

Answer (score 1):

This looks to me like the Java equivalent of creating a C/C++ macro to save typing a few letters, which I can't accept as a good practice. You'll be re-reading the code far more often than you will write it, so the "additional level of indirection" you've added will cost far more time in maintenance than you will save in development.

Answer (score 0):

> SO my question is am i right in thinking that doing above mentioned thing is inefficient? or it does not affect performance that much?

If you are mostly worried about performance, then put each variant in a separate loop, run through it a million or somesuch amount of times, and measure the time difference between executing the two variants. Chances are the difference will be negligible to nonexistent.

If you look at the byte code, I wouldn't be at all surprised if the entire function is inlined by the compiler, since all it does is wrap another call.

Comment: Looking at the bytecode is not decisive, since the call will probably be inlined runtime, by the JIT (if at all).

Comment: That's probably going to depend on the compiler used, too, but actually testing the performance of both approaches should be fairly telling. And easier.

Answer (score 0):

Do not do this.  You are simply renaming the function to fit your personal preconceptions.  Some future maintainer will have to learn neo4j, and will know the meaning of *getReferenceNode*.  Then she will see calls to *getRootNode* and think "getRootNode?  WTF is that?" Then she will go read your function, and grab something and throw it against the wall cursing your name.  Then she will refactor, inlining *getRootNode* out of existence.

We introduce functions to reduce duplication and maintenance cost.  Your function does the opposite.

Someone made a choice to use neo4j.  Learn it and use it as designed.